# What is MeasurementNanoPB.framework for?

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, frameworks, measurement

I'm just curious. In my iOS project (xCode 10) I have the framework "MeasurementNanoPB" from firebase. I tried around and my app works fine when I delete this framework. (using carthage btw.)

Does someone know what this framework does?

It's strange because when my co-worker updates all our firebase framework this framework isn't downloaded. He gets:

```
 ld: framework not found Measurement NanoPB clang
 Error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`MeasurementNanoPB` is a support library for `FirebaseAnalytics`.  If the app isn't linking `FirebaseAnalytics`, it won't need to link `MeasurementNanoPB`.